# Web socket-like mechanism on IE 9

Tags: android, networking, internet-explorer-9

For reasons which are hard to explain, some users of the app we are developing use IE 9. We currently need to implement a web socket-like channel between IE9 browsers and Android devices. The channel needs to be able to transport images between endpoints. What kind of communication channel should be used here?

Answer (score 1):

This is awkward but you'll need to turn your Android app into a small REST-api server to server request from your IE9 client.

Take reference to such lib for Android like: https://github.com/koush/AndroidAsync

Then from your IE 9 client, make REST call to your android-server.